# How to add a value to a.getAttribute in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to javascript, jquery
I have a form text field. I am trying to append a value to it. and that field is going to add to google maps places. But it showing a.getAttribute is  not a function.

```
var input = document.getElementById('target');
input2= input+"dubai ";

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input2);
```

when i add input2 it is showing a.getAttribute is not function.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('target');` returns an element that has ID set as '**target**'. With `input2= input+"dubai ";` you are trying to concatenate string with HTML element which won't work.

So if you want to add value to it, just do:

```
var input = document.getElementById('target');
input.value= "dubai "; //add value to it

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

Comment: The value dubai is showing in text field but here i just append a value and pass to searchbox only not to display in text field

Comment: @whoami seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/r5572yj9/ , you need to set proper lattitude and longitude values, as in the fiddle the values are set randomly

Comment: Thanks for your help. But here my task is i should not dubai to user. What ever user types. I want to get that value and append to dubai. and show the result of dubai and uservalue

Answer (score 0):

input is a object, dubai type = String ;They can not add up